# react native use other class function from stacknavigator

Tags: react-native

So i have a function called openControlPanel inside my index.js

```
class App extends Component {
    closeControlPanel = () => {
        this._drawer.close()
    };
    openControlPanel = () => {
        this._drawer.open()
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Drawer
                ref={(ref) => this._drawer = ref}
                content={<Promo />}
            >
                <Root />
            </Drawer>

         );
     }
 }

 export default App;
```

i wish to call these open and close function from within my StackNavigator inside router.js

```
export const Root = StackNavigator({
Tabs: {
    // screen: Object.assign(Tabs,{navigationOptions}),
    screen: Tabs,
    navigationOptions: ({_drawer}) => ({
        title:'hoho',
        headerLeft: <Button buttonStyle={{marginLeft:10}} title="DR" onPress={() => _drawer.open()} />

    })
}});
```

actually i can use default DrawerNavigator from react-navigation, but it seems the drawer is not really customizable...